# PHP - Redirect to a page after sending email

Tags: php

Hi guys I have the ff codes:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "gogel.rob@gmail.com";
$subject = "Chick SEO Contact Form: New Email from $name";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank you!";
?>
```

Right now its only redirecting the page to a simple echo page with text "Thank you"

Is there anyway we can redirect the user to this URL https://recurpost.com/ once the form was submitted and the email was sent instead of sending it to echo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: you can use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` for redirection. Also, to show the message "Thank you" on  "https://recurpost.com/" you can use sesion as well.

Comment: Use php header function.

Comment: I treid this on my server but it returned this Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd1/277XX77/public_html/contact.php:1) in /storage/ssd1/277/15414277/public_html/contact.php on line 11

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Php header function. Instead of the echo, you can use the following:

```
header("Location: https://recurpost.com/");
```

The above code will include a "location" header in the Http response. This will cause the browser to redirect the user to the given url. See the [documentation for the header function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I treid this on my server but it returned this `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd1/277XX77/public_html/contact.php:1) in /storage/ssd1/277/15414277/public_html/contact.php on line 11`

Comment: Well the documentation for the header function mentions: "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.". So your code must be sending output before the header function is called

Comment: also check header before sending with headers_sent()

Answer (score 0):

**Try using**

```
<?php
  echo "
        <script>
                window.location.replace('https://urdomain.org/successpage');
        </script>
    ";
```